# i have my app in azure add and want to connect azure service bus?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azureservicebus, azure-ad-msal

I have my app in azure ad and  want to connect azure service bus ?

I added service principle inside identity role of service bus.

but still its not allowing me to access service bus from service principle

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
az role assignment create --role "Azure Service Bus Data Owner" --assignee {}  --scope /subscriptions/{}/resourceGroups/cortex-audit-resourcegrp/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/Az-ServiceBusDemo
```

Add this role and it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).